# Google Material Design Web how to change 'text fields outline color' if I am using cdn in html head

Tags: html, css, material-design, googleio

Actually I am making a website using html, css, and normal javascript. I am trying to use google material components using the CDN way. I have perfectly imported a outlined text input field in my website. But now the problem is I want to change the outline color of the component. but I can't be able to change it from sass by using classname. I have tried a lot to find out a solution but unabled.

Please show me a way how can I change the attributes of the meterial elements.heres my html part...
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uWtl.png)
and here's the output...
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5sl.jpg)
and link to the website - https://material.io/components/text-fields/web#outlined-text

I just want to make the outlines white.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your css file after cdn link so it can override cdn styles

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".style.css">
```